# Jquery FullCalendar + reload events in eventDrop function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar

I need to reload my Jquery Fullcalendar with an ajax call but ain't sure how to rebind the calendar again without recreating another one, basically what I am doing below is to initialize my calendar events by fetching the dates with my GetSchedule method.

When an eventDrop occurs, I will need to fetch the new set of data from my GetSchedule method and reload the fullcalendar again, reason being some events aren't suppose to be in some dates.

The below code will recreate another fullcalendar when an eventDrop occurs. Can someone please kindly advice. Thanks.

```
  var sDate;
  var buildingEvents;

  function initialize(loadevents) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Account/WebServices/WebServices.asmx/GetSchedule",
            data: "{'custId': '" + $('#<%= hdnCustId.ClientID %>').val() + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) { sDate = result.d; }
        });

        var allEvent = "";
        buildingEvents = $.map(sDate, function(item) {
            allEvent += item + "&";

            var SplitResult = item.split("||");
            var eventInfo = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < SplitResult.length; i++) {
                eventInfo[i] = SplitResult[i];
            }

            var SplitResult_0 = eventInfo[0].split("|");

            $('#<%= hdnAllCalendarEvents.ClientID %>').val(allEvent);

            return {
                id: eventInfo[0],
                start: eventInfo[1],
                title: eventInfo[2] + ' ' + '(' + ' ' + SplitResult_0[4] + ' ' + ')'
            };
        });

        if (loadevents) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: buildingEvents,
            });
        }
    }


       $(document).ready(function () {

        initialize(false);

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            eventDragStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
                var d = new Date();
                d = event.start;
                $('#<%= hdnSwapDayFrm.ClientID %>').val(d.toString('MM/dd/yyyy'));
            },
            eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
                $('#<%= hdnOrderNpkSchSetDailyNameId.ClientID %>').val(event.id);
                $('#<%= hdnAddDays.ClientID %>').val(dayDelta);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Account/WebServices/WebServices.asmx/SwapDay",
                    data: "{'hdnOrderNpkSchSetDailyNameId': '" + $('#<%= hdnOrderNpkSchSetDailyNameId.ClientID %>').val() + "', 'hdnAddDays': '" + $('#<%= hdnAddDays.ClientID %>').val() + "', 'hdnAllCalendarEvents': '" + $('#<%= hdnAllCalendarEvents.ClientID %>').val() + "', 'hdnAddDays': '" + $('#<%= hdnAddDays.ClientID %>').val() + "', 'hdnSwapDayFrm': '" + $('#<%= hdnSwapDayFrm.ClientID %>').val() + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result) {

                    }
                });

                initialize(true);
            },
            events: buildingEvents
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide a function to `events` that calls your end point:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            success: function(data) {
                var events = parseEvents(data);
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And then inside the `eventDrop` function you could call `refetchEvents`, so FullCalendar will call the `events` function again and rerender the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

You can check out the relevant documentation here: [events (as a function)](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) and [refetchEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/).